# how to convert white color pixel into other color if image is a binary boundary image?

Tags: matlab

I am presenting following boundary image which is in binary format

boundary image

[image]

I want to convert the white pixel into different color, at a time one color should be used.

how can we do this?

```
 image = imread('binaryImage.png');

 %Sysnex to convert into different color image ?%
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start a new script and paste the following function on it then save it on the same folder of your project then you can use the function whenever you want to convert the image into color you should provide the binary image as first parameter and the RGB color as the second parameter for example if you want the color red you can use like myRGB = BW2RGB(myBinaryim,[255,0,0])

```
    function RGBimage = BW2RGB(BWimage,RGBcolor)
    RGBimage(:,:,1)=BWimage;
    RGBimage(:,:,2)=BWimage;
    RGBimage(:,:,3)=BWimage;
    RGBimage = uint8(RGBimage);
    for m = 1:size(BWimage,1)
     for n=1:size(BWimage,2)
      if(BWimage(m,n)==1)
        RGBimage(m,n,1)=RGBcolor(1);
        RGBimage(m,n,2)=RGBcolor(2);
        RGBimage(m,n,3)=RGBcolor(3);
      end
     end
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a grayscale image, you can just do :

```
coloredImage = image*color_you_want;
```

For a real colors, this is a little bit different since you need each pixel converted into an RGB pixel.

```
color = [0.2, 0.8, 0.3];
coloredImage = zeros(size(image)(1), size(image)(2), 3);
coloredImage(:,:,1) = image*color(1);
coloredImage(:,:,2) = image*color(2);
coloredImage(:,:,3) = image*color(3);
```

You can easily adapt it with a `for` loop, and thus set different colors. You transform your color vector into a matrix and for each step of the loop, you take the color represented by a specific row.